# Distance between two location by meters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which contains latitude and longitude for objects. I want to find object near me (about 50 meters distance).

I will send my location (latitude and longitude) and this query give me objects which near me. And also whict index can i use for speed?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not simple and depends on the level of accuracy you need. The "simple" method is to use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the "straight line" distance. But this doesn't account for curvature nor things like altitude differences.

There are some functions in some versions of SQL, but I don't know what's available in postgresql. Try looking at this page for lots of good info:
https://kanoki.org/2019/02/14/how-to-find-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-and-longitude-using-python-and-sql/

As for speed, what dynamic information do you have? Change in Lat/Long? Time to get from one point to another? You can't calculate speed with only one data point.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has an optional module called [`earthdistance`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/earthdistance.html) that you can use for this. One the module is installed, you can do things like:

```
select lat, long
from mytable
where point(lon, lat) <@> point(:mylon, :mylat) < 50 / 1609.344
```

Where `(:mylon, :mylat)` are the parameter that represent your current longitude and latitude. This query gives you the objects that are less than 50 meters away from you (`1609.344` is used as a rough estimate that represents the number of meter per mile).